# How to arrange plots in vertical order in ggplotly 'facet_wrap' function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, facet-wrap, ggplotly

I have a dataset with 7 columns which contains first row as a names and a remaining 6 columns are values. I need to create a density plot for the data. Here's a sample dataset:

```
structure(list(`Majority protein IDs` = c("P19882", "P38999", 
"P34227", "Q12335", "P40893", "P33416", "Q04947", "Q12074", "P38116", 
"P32598", "P38221", "P52910", "P0CX51;P0CX52", "Q02805", "P50861", 
"Q02821", "P53691", "P19414", "Q04013", "Q07799", "P47039"), 
    A1 = c(964860000, 46301000, 135090000, 126280000, 96191000, 
    91552000, 75231000, 76684000, 6150500, 21904000, 55134000, 
    231070000, 259060000, 7304500, 180320000, 22025000, 79510000, 
    677560000, 5994400, 18950000, 3468200), A2 = c(1074500000, 
    42888000, 125590000, 1.27e+08, 68911000, 93280000, 66457000, 
    69568000, 4848600, 20342000, 52573000, 242230000, 286970000, 
    5770200, 190140000, 22305000, 87598000, 673050000, 6459300, 
    21634000, 3115400), A3 = c(1021200000, 56550000, 117190000, 
    124730000, 69026000, 80712000, 55917000, 71989000, 5390500, 
    19299000, 51348000, 213050000, 254080000, 6976000, 181280000, 
    20951000, 83504000, 664590000, 6155300, 21158000, 2940600
    ), B1 = c(846340000, 34713000, 95928000, 121440000, 16256000, 
    63182000, 46570000, 59008000, 1465600, 24838000, 48464000, 
    176140000, 175320000, 8738500, 120870000, 24496000, 75694000, 
    524780000, 4373900, 16281000, 5801700), B2 = c(921740000, 
    35240000, 109990000, 111250000, 39047000, 74125000, 51027000, 
    65971000, 3027100, 36529000, 39712000, 179630000, 218240000, 
    8092500, 152610000, 26032000, 62681000, 587100000, 4887000, 
    18454000, 3811100), B3 = c(908710000, 38475000, 106400000, 
    113590000, 36745000, 74175000, 48912000, 64201000, 3073300, 
    39069000, 40650000, 206350000, 220280000, 8673100, 154260000, 
    30254000, 61422000, 617900000, 5561000, 17102000, 5486600
    )), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I used the below function for making the density plot:

```
Densityplot_data <- function (data){
  variable <- value <- NULL
  
  new_data <- as.data.frame(data)
  new_data <- new_data[,-1]
  
  options(warn = -1)
  density_plot <- new_data %>%
    tibble::as.tibble() %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=value) ) +
    ggplot2::geom_density (fill= "#69b3a2") +
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free", nrow = 3, dir = "v")+
    ggplot2::theme_gray()+
    ggplot2::theme(text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 20))
  return(plotly::ggplotly(density_plot))
}

Densityplot_data(testdata)
```

Which returns the plot below:

[image]

But I need to get the columns in the vertical order like,

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
```

Comment: I think there was actually a nice opportunity to demonstrate how to refactor for use with `facet_grid` - redirecting to this other answer imo is getting people to rely on `facet_wrap` in situations where a grid formulation may allow for clearer code.

Comment: [`ggplotly` doesn't support the `dir=` option](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1243). You'll need to set the levels in the order you want them to display.

Comment: About your follow up question; I created another dataframe ```testdata %>% mutate(C1 = A1, C2 = A2, C3 = A3) -> testdata2``` and my solution worked fine. https://i.imgur.com/H4K0mkN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
Densityplot_data <- function (data){
  variable <- value <- NULL
  
  new_data <- as.data.frame(data)
  new_data <- new_data[,-1]
  options(warn = -1)
  
  density_plot <- new_data %>%
    tibble::as.tibble() %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(order_hlp = as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]", "",variable))) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(order_hlp) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(variable_fac = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))) %>% 
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=value) ) +
    ggplot2::geom_density (fill= "#69b3a2") +
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable_fac, scales="free", nrow = 3)+
    ggplot2::theme_gray()+
    ggplot2::theme(text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 20))
  return(plotly::ggplotly(density_plot))
}

Densityplot_data(testdata)
```

[image]

Comment: Sure. The suggested duplicate technically answers your question, however it doesn't cover the `regex` part of it. That's why I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with `facet_grid` and a little refactoring:

```
library(tidyverse)

# with df = structure(...)
as_tibble(df) |> 
  pivot_longer(-1) |> 
  separate_wider_position(name, widths = c(grp = 1, num = 1)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  geom_density(fill= "#69b3a2") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(num), cols = vars(grp))
```

[image]

Just wrap with `plotly::ggplotly()` if you want to go that route

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my analysis, I have to mention the column name as the plot title. So the above plot format may not be a well representation for my analysis.  But I will use your suggestion in another place.